# "sql_mode=only_full_group_by" incompatibility error

Tags: mysql

My SQL statement worked fine in another local server, but after trying out my project in recently installed lamp server it is showing the following error-

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'newmesssages.send_date' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The statement-

```
SELECT COUNT(reciever) as total, send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name 
FROM (SELECT * FROM messages_view WHERE reciever = 17 AND viewed_by_reciever is NULL order by send_date DESC) 
AS newmesssages 
GROUP BY sender ORDER BY send_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by all the columns that don´t aggregate,like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(reciever) as total, send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name 
FROM (SELECT * 
     FROM messages_view 
     WHERE reciever = 17 AND viewed_by_reciever is NULL order by send_date DESC) 
     AS newmesssages 
GROUP BY send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name 
ORDER BY send_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

If you don´t want to group by those columns, you need to take them off the SELECT.

The other solution it´s to change the sql_mode doing this:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@sql_mode, ',only_full_group_by', '');
```

And at last, you had an error in your SQL, you where grouping by `sender` but you don´t have that column name

**EDITED**:
You can do it this way:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(reciever)  
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM messages_view 
              WHERE reciever = 17 AND viewed_by_reciever is NULL 
              order by send_date DESC) AS newmesssages 
        GROUP BY send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name),
        send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name 
FROM (SELECT * 
     FROM messages_view 
     WHERE reciever = 17 AND viewed_by_reciever is NULL order by send_date DESC) 
ORDER BY send_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

I think this could work

Comment: This works, however, I get all the unread messages from a user instead of just the last message and total unread messages from that user

Comment: If you want the last message, you have to do a different query than you are doing

Comment: `SET sql_mode = ' '` is dangerous there are more sql modes that do needs to be active.. Better is to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@sql_mode, ',only_full_group_by', '');` this only removes the only_full_group_by option and keeps the other sql modes active.

Answer (score 0):

this code on your query `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disable

for Mysql:-- use this code on your query :

```
$set_mode = "SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))"; $resultss = mysqli_query($this->dbh,$set_mode);
```

for codeigniter :-- use this code on your query :

```
$this->db->query("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));") ;
```

as for u:

```
$set_mode = "SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))"; $resultss = mysqli_query($this->dbh,$set_mode);
SELECT COUNT(reciever) as total, send_date, message, sender_username, sender_name 
FROM (SELECT * FROM messages_view WHERE reciever = 17 AND viewed_by_reciever is NULL order by send_date DESC) 
AS newmesssages 
GROUP BY sender ORDER BY send_date DESC LIMIT 20
```